# Displaying a search bar on top of Contact ACTION_PICK Intent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-contacts

When firing off a `Intent.ACTION_PICK` Intent to pick contacts, how can I make it display the search bar and the "New Contact" plus-sign button on top of the contact list? This action defaults to a view which only shows the contact list.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I looked for standard activities, and there's also ACTION_SEARCH. Try using that on the contacts URI, perhaps it'll work (haven't tried it myself).

Comment: Doesn't seem to solve it. Doing that gives me an ActivityNotFound Exception when targeting a 2.2.2 device.